# TortoiseHG hg clone doesn't work error 255

Tags: tortoisehg

According to the [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20101002113432/https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/bitbucket+101) from Atlassian I have installed the version 2.2.1 of tortoiseHg but i am getting the next error when i try clone my repository.

```
% hg clone --verbose -- hg clone https://mymercurialrepository .
repository hg clone https://mymercurialrepository not found
[command returned code 255 Sun Jul 22 17:42:51 2012]
```

What is wrong?
btw:before to have installed the version 2.2.1 i had other version using kiln. do i need to install something else? edit some file?

Comment: I am getting same issue as I have sated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15728490/892788). What did you do to resolve this problem?

Comment: if you see in the post above.. you will see that "hg clone" is duplicate.. may be you did the same..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong command string:

```
% hg clone --verbose https://mymercurialrepository..
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the answer clearer, I got this from [here](http://support.hglabhq.com/discussions/problems/728-tortoisehg-error-command-returned-code-255).

You're just pasting the wrong thing and HgLab is a bit confused here. To clone using TortoiseHg, you only need the URL part, i.e. everything after the hg clone substring as shown in the image below:

[image]