# Cloning using Tortoise-Hg abort in middle[command returned code 255]

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, codeplex

I am using [Tortoise-Hg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/) for **cloning a fork** from [CodePlex](http://nearforums.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c1f7efa1d5b1) and **cloning stops in the middle of the process**. I have tried it more than **6** times and it does have a problem.

I am using the **visual client of Tortoise-Hg** and I gave the source as `https://hg.codeplex.com/forks/xxx/xxxx` and selected a destination

First used **compressed** method

This is what appeared in the command prompt

```
 % hg clone --verbose -- https://hg.codeplex.com/forks/xxx/xxxx xxxx
```

But the process start quite fast and then it get hung up.

```
requesting all changes
adding changesets[Happen Fast]
adding manifests[Happen Fast]
adding file changes[Hangs in the middle]
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: stream ended unexpectedly (got 147721 bytes, expected 422805)
[command returned code 255 Sun Mar 31 15:52:26 2013]
```

Then I tried **uncompressed** method

```
 % hg clone --uncompressed --verbose -- https://hg.codeplex.com/forks/xxx/xxxx xxxx
```

That also stops in the middle of the process.

```
streaming all changes
4033 files to transfer, 37.2 MB of data
abort: unexpected response from remote server: empty string
[command returned code 255 Sun Mar 31 15:22:44 2013]
```

I tried it the 7th time and It went far more than previous tries but got more bytes `got 74673 bytes, expected 256973`

What is the wrong with this, I have used same version of Tortoise-Hg before for cloning [CodePlex](http://nearforums.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c1f7efa1d5b1) projects. This is very time consuming. Is there something wrong of what I am doing?. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to do the cloning, Internet connection was the reason. Internet was heavy for me during the initial trails. That's what have caused the problem. Now since the internet connection is in quite good level of speed, Cloning worked fine. There were no hangings. If you are facing the same issue, Basic check is a good internet connection. Hope this will help someone.

Edit: This has again happened to me, But this time I tried cloning using command prompt. It also worked fine. :)

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Thanks for the hint to use command prompt.. it seems to be working with command prompt.

Comment: I got the same error with the command prompt as well. Is there any other way to clone repo?

Comment: I have a good connection. I can only clone little projects (repository size < 15MB). Bigger projects (40MB) don't work, No matter if I use Workbench or command prompt. :(

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that comes across this I ran into this issue on our internal Mercurial server (not CodePlex) and fixed it.

Our setup is Mercurial running on Windows Server 2008 R2 using [HgWeb](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebInIisOnWindows) running under IIS.  The problem we encountered was a CGI timeout.  Cloning our entire repository exceeded the 15 min default timeout for CGI.  The fix was to increase the timeout.  This can be done in the IIS Manager.

1. Open the IIS Manager
2. Select the website
3. Open the CGI panel
4. Edit the timeout
5. Click Apply
6. Restart the Pool for the website

If internet performance was a factor with CodePlex I am guessing a similar timeout is the culprit.

Comment: I am using wFASTCGI on Windows Server 2008 R2. I was facing the same issue so I changed the timeout to 600s. This worked for me. As the repository grows unless it is split, I will need to change it again at a later date.